# Handle Json data and pass it to object for further use

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

For instance I have some JSON data like below (***The JSON data is just an example, I just want to give out some fake, make up and wrong format JSON as example***)

```
 cata :[{
       name:test1,
       data:['abc1, abc2'  , 'abc3,abc4']
      }
        name:test2,
       data:['abc5, abc6'  , 'abc7,abc8']
    }]
```

And indeed I need to render it to frontend, therefore I made a new object and try to push data into it

```
var name = "";
var key= [];
for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    name .push(cata[i].name)
    key.push(cata[i].data.join(' + '));
}
var rehandle = {
     name : name,
     key : key
  }
```

The above is just how i do it now, and which do no provide the desire result, i want to know how could i restore it so i can change the format from

```
 ['abc5, abc6'  , 'abc7,abc8']
```

to

```
abc5+abc6 , abc7+abc8
```

**UPDATE version of the question:**

I think i better explain it step by step:

1. I have some raw data
2. I have a row of "data" in each set of data
   (E.g:**data:['abc1, abc2'  , 'abc3,abc4']**)
3. I want to change it's format to **abc1+abc2  , abc3+abc4** and store it to another variable
4. I will pass the variable store **abc1+abc2  , abc3+abc4** to an object

5.Render it one by one in a table

**UPDATE 2**
I have seen @pill's answer, am i able to render the data like

```
   for(var i=0;i<cata.length;i++){
                  var trythis = trythis + '<td>'+name[i]+'</td>' +                '<td>'+data[i]+'</td>'
                }
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're asking here. Do you actually have a problem?

Comment: so basically i want to handle the data and put them in and object and render it in a table

Comment: And whats stopping you do that ? I mean whats the problem ? You dont know how to access properties of JSON ?

Comment: do you mind to go in a chat, because my question is bit wield

Comment: Why are you trying to push onto a string?

Answer (score 1):

To format your data from

> `['abc5, abc6'  , 'abc7,abc8']`

to

> abc5+abc6 , abc7+abc8

you'd simply use

```
data.map(k => k.split(/,\s*/).join('+')).join(' , ')
```

or the ES5 version

```
data.map(function(k) {
    return k.split(/,\s*/).join('+');
}).join(' , ');
```

---

For example...

```js
var cata = [{"name":"test1","data":["abc1, abc2","abc3,abc4"]},{"name":"test2","data":["abc5, abc6","abc7,abc8"]}];

var rehandle = cata.reduce(function(o, d) {
  o.name.push(d.name);
  o.key.push(d.data.map(function(k) {
    return k.split(/,\s*/).join('+');
  }).join(' , '));
  return o;
}, {
  name: [],
  key: []
});

console.log('rehandle:', rehandle);
```

Note that I had to fix up your data formatting

Comment: i actually don't need to create an table by javascript.

Comment: Then you need to improve your question

Comment: @anson920520 see my updated answer. I just had to cater for your CSV data having optional spaces in the separator

Comment: node.js doesn't seem like able to read  .map(k => k.split(/,\s*/).join('+'))
        .join(' , ')

Comment: @anson920520 what version? Any recent NodeJS runtime should be able to handle arrow functions. I've added a legacy version to my answer

Comment: can i put it in an object?

Comment: @anson920520 the result is a string so you can do whatever you want with it. You **really** need to be specific about what you want in your question

Comment: i have updated the question, hopefully this would explain my question better.

Comment: @anson920520 I'm not really following you as I've already stated the result is a string so you can assign it to anything you want. I've updated my answer with an *"object"* example

Comment: may i please have a legacy version please?

Comment: @anson920520 you should really update your JS runtime

Comment: i see the format has been changed but all the data store in one array now, which it shouldn't be like that